# Get control size in millimeter

Tags: c#, wpf, size, dpi

I'm trying to show a map in my app programmed in C# (WPF). Is there any way to convert a `Control` size from pixel to centimeter?

I tried this code:

```
PresentationSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(myControl);

double dpiX = 96.0f * source.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M11; 

double sizeInCentiMeter = myControl.Width / dpiX * 2.54;
```

But I get the size with percentage of error. I mean that the the real size is always about 0.25 more than calculated size.

You can assume that dpi = 96.

Comment: Is the dpi actually 96? That seems the most likely source of error by far.

Comment: is there any way to calculate it as accurate as possible?

Comment: It depends entirely on the display device. Unfortunately, it looks like there is no way for display devices to report their physical dimensions to Windows, so there is no way for Windows to accurately calculate the dpi of a device.

Comment: @JasonWatkins is right.  In the simple case of an LCD display, reporting physical size makes sense, but think of a projector: how would it calculate its dpi?  It would depend on the projector's distance from the screen.  The best you can do is ask the user.

Comment: Control sizes are already in inches with a unit of 1/96", not pixels.  No point in using DPI, just multiply by 25.4 to get mm.  This does beg the question what you call "real size".  Don't use a ruler on the monitor, displayed sizes are only an approximation.  Monitor DPI doesn't have to be exact, perceived DPI depends how far you sit away from the monitor.